# Sorting a reference to an array of rows where each row is stored as a hash

Tags: sorting, perl, hashref, arrayref

I'm trying to sort the following data structure in Perl, by location_id.

```
my $employees = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(qq[
    SELECT name, type, code, emp_cat_id,
           percentage, location_id
    FROM table_1
],{ Slice => {} });
 
for my $row (@$employees) {
   push @{
      $args->{employees}{ $row->{emp_cat_id} }
   }, $row;
}
```

Example:

```
123 => [
   {
      percentage  => 0.25,
      code        => "XYZ",
      name        => "John Doe",
      type        => "pt",
      location_id => 001,
      emp_cat_id  => 123

   }
],
555 => [
   {
      percentage  => 0.50,
      code        => "ZZZ"
      name        => "Chris Cringle",
      type        => "ft",
      location_id => 007,
      emp_cat_id  => 555

   },
   {
      percentage  => 0.25,
      code        => "XXX"
      name        => "Tom Thompson",
      type        => "pt",
      location_id => 002,
      emp_cat_id  => 555

   }
]
```

For every emp_cat_id, I need the structure to have the location_ids in asc order.

I've tried the following, but I get "useless use of sort in void context at line #" or "useless use of sort in scalar context at line #" errors.

```
$args->{employees} = sort {
   $a->{location_id} <=> $b->{location_id}
} $args->{employees};
```

Any help understanding the sort is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sorting the array(ref) at `emp_cat_id` of `555`, then of `123`, and so need to dereference for sorting those  arrayrefs. So

```
foreach my $id (keys $args->{employees}) { 
    @{ $args->{employees}{$id} } = sort { 
            $a->{location_id} <=> $b->{location_id} 
        }
        @{ $args->{employees}{$id} } 
}
```

(tested with the structure shown in the question, omitted here)<sup>†</sup>

Doing anything like this loses `007` into `7`. This is of course possible to fix, let me know if it matters.

If you really have only the key `employees` then consider extracting the `$args->{employees}` hashref and working with that. It'll be way easier

```
use Storable qw(dclone);

my $employees = dclone $args->{employees};  # need deep copy
```

---

<sup>†</sup> Oh well, here's the whole thing

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my $args = {
    employees => {
        123 => [
            {
                percentage  => 0.25,
                code        => "XYZ",
                name        => "John Doe",
                type        => "pt",
                location_id => 001,
                emp_cat_id  => 123
            }
        ],
        555 => [
            {
                percentage  => 0.50,
                code        => "ZZZ",
                name        => "Chris Cringle",
                type        => "ft",
                location_id => 007,
                emp_cat_id  => 555

            },
            {
                percentage  => 0.25,
                code        => "XXX",
                name        => "Tom Thompson",
                type        => "pt",
                location_id => 002,
                emp_cat_id  => 555

            }
        ]
    }
};

foreach my $id (keys $args->{employees}) {
    @{ $args->{employees}{$id} } = sort {
            $a->{location_id} <=> $b->{location_id}
        }
        @{ $args->{employees}{$id} }
}

dd $args;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a hashref where each element is an arrayref of hashrefs that should be sorted based on a key of that inside hashref?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $hashref = {
    123 => [
        {
            percentage  => 0.25,
            code        => "XYZ",
            name        => "John Doe",
            type        => "pt",
            location_id => 001,
            emp_cat_id  => 123
        }
        ],
    555 => [
        {
            percentage  => 0.50,
            code        => "ZZZ",
            name        => "Chris Cringle",
            type        => "ft",
            location_id => 007,
            emp_cat_id  => 555
        },
        {
            percentage  => 0.25,
            code        => "XXX",
            name        => "Tom Thompson",
            type        => "pt",
            location_id => 002,
            emp_cat_id  => 555
        }
        ]
};

foreach my $arrayref (values %$hashref) {
    @$arrayref = sort { $a->{location_id} <=> $b->{location_id} } @$arrayref;
}

print Dumper($hashref);
```

The important part you're missing is in dereferencing the arrayrefs. `@$arrayref` instead of just `$arrayref`.